# Push Notification acts different when app is closed

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have handled my notifications in AppDelegate with these functions :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any])
```

and :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
```

but I get different reactions from clicking the notifications. for example, when I have a deep-link it works fine when the app is in background or foreground but when the app is closed the deep-link won't work. 
I'm new in IOS so, sorry if my question is basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the app is closed, and you press on a pushnoitification, the push notifictaion recieve messages don't get called. Instead, the [application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application?language=objc) method gets called(as it is supposed to).

The trick is to check for notofication in the `launchOptions` dictionary.

```
if let remoteNotificationInfo = launchOptions?[.remoteNotification] as? [AnyHashable : Any] {
     dealWithRemoteNotification(remoteNotificationInfo)
}

func dealWithRemoteNotification(_ userInfo:[AnyHashable : Any]) {
}
```

Comment: is it the same for the function with completionHandler?  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)

Comment: Yes it is same for all delegate methods.

Comment: just another question. is there any option for launchOptions that works with completion handler?